# How to choose a BJT used as a diode-connected BJT

Tags: diodes, bjt, datasheet, class-ab

I am choosing components for the following circuit, which will be used as a class AB amplifier:
[image: Schematic]
The resistors will be chosen to bias the transistors. I chose Q1 such that the quiescent current Iq = 1.2A (what I want to provide to the load) at Vbe = 0.75V (ZXTC2063E6).
I am now trying to choose Q2 such that a current of 10-50mA will have a drop of 0.75V. However, I am very confused as to how to use the datasheet to find what the voltage across will be.

My first thought was to use the Vbe,on vs Ic curve, but it states that Vce = 5V, which will not be the case.
[image: Vbe,on vs Ic curve]

Then I thought to use the Vce vs Ib curve. I used the hfe vs Ic curve to find the gain and calculate Ib from Ic, then from the curve find what Vce is. That sounds logical but Im not entirely sure thats how its done. Also, it looks like <50mA is too low of a current to have a 0.75V drop.
[image]

I thought of simply using two diodes. That would make the datasheet straightforward and simple, but Im not sure if it'll follow Q1 in its temperature response, and I also am doing this to learn.

What am I supposed to look at in the datasheet to help me find the voltage drop for a certain current? Also, Im open for suggestions on improvements or corrections of flaws.

Comment: This will not work in a real world circuit, thermal runaway is hard to avoid. Use 0.1 ohm resistors in the emitter path of Q1A and Q1B to compensate minor Ufwd differences.

Answer (score 0):

Q1 and Q2 should be the same transistor part number. Mount Q1A close to Q2A and Q1B close to Q2B on the same heatsink. Match them for Vb: Q1A to Q2A, Q1B to Q2B. And add a bit of emitter degeneration to Q1 to preclude thermal runaway. A fraction of an Ohm would usually suffice, but you have to measure it and actually see the runaway without emitter degeneration, so that you can see what value of Re will fix it. Then go a bit higher.

Comment: if I match the transistors, then the current drawn will be double what Im supplying to the load, right? Im trying to get the same Vbe at a much lower current  to have better power consumption

Comment: Also, would using FETs instead of BJTs be a better solution to the thermal runaway?